# Superimposing a Matlab plot over a python plot/image

Tags: python, image, matlab, python-2.7, plot

I would like to compare a bargraph obtained with Python (using matplotlib) and the plot of a function from Matlab. To do so, I thought about superimposing the Matlab plot on the image of the bargraph.

However I am pretty new to matlab (python as well), so I don't know how to do this. I've been looking at a couple of questions relating this topic, however I really don't understand what I should do.

[image: Bargraph from Python]

```
A1 = 80;
A2 = 72;
B1 = 470;
B2 = 220;
D1 = 500;
D2 = 700;
T = 0.136994238205;
X = -60:0.1:60;
Y1 = A1*sqrt(D1*pi)*exp(-(X.^2)/(4*D1*T)) + B1*exp(-(X.^2)/(4*D1*T));

img = imread('bar2.png');

imagesc(X,Y1,flipud(img));
hold on;
plot(X,Y1,'r','linewidth',1.5);
set(gca, 'ydir', 'normal');
```

This is the code that I have tried, but clearly it doesn't work, I have just been trying to copy and understand the code given in other questions here. How can I superimpose this function `plot(X,Y1)` on the bargraph? I know I should show more coding work, but I have no idea on how to tackle this and online I can't find anything helpful. How do I superimpose in general?

Is there a way to adjust it, because it seems like I should traslate it.
This is what I get
[image: Plot over Bar Graph]

Answer (score 1):

If you have two graphs (say .png files) and wants to superimpose the images, then use blend(). Below code will superimpose all the images on "images2/" folder and gives you a single final image.

If you blend() more images, the quality (color, brightness, contrast) of the image may deteriorate. Use ImageEnhance to improve the quality of the image. The value of alpha can be tuned to get a perfect blend.

```
import Image
import os
import cv2
import ImageEnhance
listing = os.listdir("images2/") 
new_img = Image.new("RGBA", (800, 600), "white") 

for file in listing:
    im = Image.open(path1 + file)  
    new_img = Image.blend(im, new_img, 2.0)
    new_img = Image.blend(new_img,im,0.5)

enhancer = ImageEnhance.Color(new_img)
new_img = enhancer.enhance(3)
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(new_img)
new_img = enhancer.enhance(2)
new_img.save("new008.png","PNG")
```